# How can I loop this function through the same list multiple times?

Tags: loops, prolog

I have this code to iterate through a list a replace characters in it:

```
replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):- 
  I > -1,
  NI is I-1,
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
replace(L, _, _, L).

replaceX(A,_,0,_,A):- !.
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
  Index1 is Index+1,
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
  replaceX(BLine,Index1,NumElm1+1,Elm,NLine).
```

If I give it a list to replace such as:

```
replaceX([b, b, b, b, b], 1, 3, r, Y).
```

I get `Y = [b, r, r, r, b],`

How can I do this multiple times at once to get the following?

```
[r, r, r, b, b], [b, r, r, r, b], [b, b, r, r, r]
```

Comment: You could start by explaining what the arguments to `replaceX` mean, and how they relate to your result.

Comment: I believe I have figured the issue out, though I now have a different problem. Anyways, here are what the arguments to `replaceX` mean.

`replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine)`

`Line` is the list you are trying to replace the values in.

`Index` is the position in the list where you start replacing values.

`NumElm` is the number of elements you are replacing in total.

`Elm` is the character or number that replaces the other values in the list.

`NLine` is the list where the output will go.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to loop my previous code, though it has its own errors I'll try to fix in another thread.

```
loopReplace(ListToReplace, Size, NewList) :-
    length(ListToReplace, Len),
    TotalCount is Len-2,
    between(0, TotalCount, Iterations),
    replaceX(ListToReplace, Iterations, Size, 'r', NewList).
```

Sample Input:

```
placeRedBlocks(5, X), loopReplace(X, Y).
```

Output:

```
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [r, r, r, b, b]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, b, b]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [r, r, r, r, b]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, r, b]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [r, r, r, r, r]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, r, r]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, r, b]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, r, r]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, r, r]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, b, r, r, r]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, b, r, r, r]
X = [b, b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, b, r, r, r]
```